# How to connect react to html using jsx phrase

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Thanks for reading this.

In React,

```js
const name = 'test';
const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('test'));
```

Meanwhile in html,

```html
...
<div class="article-body">
    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="test"></div>
    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    ...
```

I changed codes from [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)

It doesn't work but returning 'Hello' works fine,
which is

```js
const element = 'Hello';
ReactDOM.render(element, domContainer);
```

What's wrong with jsx????
Did I miss something when using jsx?

Edit :
I've tried

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

but not working either it's "Hello" or `<h1>Hello</h1>`.
The react code is in test.jsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does not come with JSX transpiler. You will have to explicitly add it to your project. Babel is one such transpiler which can help in understanding JSX syntax.

Add below babel script to your html file

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>`

And surround your code with type `text/babel` like below -

```
 <script type="text/babel">
    const name = 'test';
    const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
 </script>
```

This gives a sample example - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html